# JSF: Create a "dummy" button which does nothing?

Tags: jsf, button, usability

In our JSF web application, we have an input field where the user can enter a numeric ID, which is then looked up by the app. To help the user, the lookup is bound to "onchange", thus it will be triggered as soon as the user tabs out of the field or clicks elsewhere.

So, user enters "123", presses tab (or clicks), lookup runs. This works fine; however, for usability reasons, we also want to provide a button that users can click on, for users who will otherwise wonder "where should I click to trigger a lookup?". To do this, we'd like to provide something that looks and feels like a HTML / JSF button, but does nothing (as the click will trigger the "onchange" event anyway).

Is there a way to make a JSF button that does nothing? I tried using h:commandButton without the "action" attribute, but it still fires a request.

Comment: why not have a simple html button with same class as jsf button, did the click of button not trigger the jsf event or is it preventing it?

Comment: or an image, if your goal is the input field to lose the focus

Comment: Of course I could use an HTML button, or even just an image, but I want the additional functionality that JSF provides (such as being able to use an icon attribute, using JSF resource references for the icon, having enabled/disabled state etc.).

Comment: `<input type="button" disabled="#{bean.disabled}">` works as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p:commandButton type="button" will just provide a push button.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this question also as a usability issue, I would advise against a button in the first place if the onchange already triggers the lookup.

From a user's perspective it is confusing whether or not clicking the button is mandatory. After they have entered the field and skipped to the next, they see the lookup occur without clicking the button. If there is a button they will assume it's there for a reason.

The option that I favour in these cases is a onkeypress handler with a timeout of half a second, after which the value is looked up.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, it is a usability issue, however our stakeholders have explicitly requested both the onchange trigger *and* the button, for the reasons given in the question. The onkeypress+timeout solution is interesting, however I would be worried it could be triggered if someone hesitates during input - that could be very confusing.

Comment: I have used the solution described above for looking up the street and town for a Dutch postal code in a GWT application. The timeout triggers a regex match, and only when the pattern is complete the actual lookup is performed, during which I also change the cursor to the busy state.

Comment: Yes, the combination with regex match solves this problem- nice idea. In our case however the input is just a number (of variable length), so there is no way to know if the user is done typing.